# Writing to an XML Document in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, xml, windows-phone-7.1

I'm attempting to write some data from an object to an XML document and am following a tutorial online, however I have run into a problem which I can't seem to fathom, the code I'm using to initiate the creation of the document is`using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("myData.xml"))` and I'm getting an error with the "myData.xml", the errors I get are:

```
The best overload method match for 'System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(System.Xml.XmlWriter)'
has some invalid arguments

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Xml.XmlWriter'
```

Is XmlWriter compatible with Windows Phone? And if not will I have to change huge amounts of code that writes to the file?

Edit: Here's my code

```
        string output = SerializeToString<AppData>(rulesData);

        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(output))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("myData");

            writer.WriteElementString("Starting Cash", rulesData.myStartingCash);
            writer.WriteElementString("Land on Go Data", rulesData.myLandOnGo);
            writer.WriteElementString("Free Parking Data", rulesData.myFreeParking);
            writer.WriteElementString("Full Circuit Data", rulesData.myFullCircuit);
            writer.WriteElementString("Auction Data", rulesData.myAuction);
            writer.Flush();

            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
```

Thanks! -Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
   public static void SerializeToStream<T>(Stream stream, object model)
   {
        var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream);
        var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        s.Serialize(writer, model);
    }

    public static string SerializeToString<T>(object model)
    {
        var xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            SerializeToStream<T>(stream, model);
            var s = stream.ToArray();
            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(s, 0, s.Length);
        }
    }

    public static void SerializeToFile<T>(string filename, object model)
    {
        using (FileStream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create))
        {
            SerializeToStream<T>(stream, model);
        }
    }
```

Your code doesn't compile because you pass a string instead of a stream to XmlWriter

Usage:

```
  string output = SerializeToString<ClassName>(instanceOfClass);
```

Comment: For some reason I can't access to serializations SerializeToStream<T> and XmlSerializer, I have included System.Xml.Serialization, any ideas? Keep in mind this is on the Windows Phone 7 platform and from my previous experience it lacks some of the features you can use on desktop pplications

Comment: @TotalJargon sorry forgot to add it

Comment: @TotalJargon see last line of my answer

Comment: It's some of the code you've given me though: var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)); and var xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)); has jagged red lines under 'XmlSerializer' and the error it gives me is "The type or namespace name 'XmlSerializer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly referance?)" I have got System.Xml and System.Xml.Serialization so is there a referance I need to add or is it incompatible?

Comment: you have to add System.Xml.dll

Comment: Ah nevermind, it was the reference :) I'll keep that in mind next time I have that sort of problem, so how do I use the code? like: using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(SerializeToString("myfile.xml))?

Comment: no just call the function and pass in your object, see my edit

Comment: compiler still doesn't like XmlWriter.Create(output); or m I mistaking how I should be using it? Sorry for my incompetence, it's my first time working with XML

Comment: you dont need xmlwriter just call the function SerializeToString() as described in my answer, it does it all for you. post your code if that doesnt work

Comment: first line of SerializeToString, var xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));, gives me the error: InvalidOperationExeption was unhandled, apparently the data in my object is not public yet it's ll set to public on initiation

Comment: Ahhh thanks, so how would I create a Stream which points to the location of the file in this context?

Comment: Thanks, got it to work now, figured out how to use IsolatedStorageFileStream in the context I needed :)